# google-cast CAF cast button customization

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Any Idea how to customise the cast button that CAF provides?

Customisation that currently exists is only design based and not on a functional basis. What I am looking for is if I could assign these cast functions to be performed on any button. Is it possible?

I wanted to use that button in a cross-platform library and expose its onPress function so developers can actually design the button they want and have the functionality served to them via the library.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible for the google cast iOS SDK version 2 and 4. The latest version is v4.3.2. If you are using the latest version, you cannot implement that and you can only change the tint color. In SDK version 2 or 3 you can set image in your UIButton.